# Calculate sum of every 5 elements in array of Integer in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

In Swift 3, how can we calculate sum of every 5 elements in array of Int.

For example, we have an array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,12,23]

```
  1+2+3+4+5 = 15
  6+7+8+9+0 = 30
  12+23+0+0+0 = 35
```

The result something like this [15,30,35]

Comment: Please show what you have attempted.

Comment: Take a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795130/finding-sum-of-elements-in-swift-array

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984914/swift-equivalent-to-each-slice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/41799646/2303865 it returns the average. so it would be easy to modify it to your purpose

Comment: `let sums = stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by: 5).map { array[$0..<min($0 + 5, array.count)] }.map { $0.reduce(0, +) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution in playgroud:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var arr = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]

let chunkSize = 5
let chunks = stride(from: 0, to: arr.count, by: chunkSize).map {
    Array(arr[$0..<min($0 + chunkSize, arr.count)])
}

print(chunks)

var summ = chunks.map { $0.reduce(0, {$0 + $1}) }

print(summ)
```

**OUTPUT:**

> [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
>
> [5, 10, 15]

Take a look at:
[Finding sum of elements in Swift array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795130/finding-sum-of-elements-in-swift-array)